# Link to user's current position/page in the rep league gone?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-leagues

There used to be a `link` href field following the `member for: X years, Y months` field in my user's info displayed at the top of each of the rep leagues page list, which I would use navigate to my current position in the league:

[image]

This link disappeared a few days ago. Is this intentional or a bug? If intentional - did that functionality move elsewhere or is it completely gone?

Comment: If you go to your user profile, you'll see 'top x% overall', is that the link you're searching for?

Comment: Equivalent to that, but applicable to any of the leagues, not just the one selected in the profile.

Comment: Looks intentional and bug as well :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bit of fallout from our recent jQuery upgrade.

We were using some feature that has been removed between the versions we did use - I have worked around it now and things work as expected now.

Comment: Yes, that was it, it's working fine now. Thx.